# FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader error: 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bbb347d8' when launching app on Xcode (flutter app)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an error when I'm trying to build my flutter app on Xcode:

```
2023-06-30 12:10:48.763891+0200 Runner[73911:650250] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
2023-06-30 12:10:50.032108+0200 Runner[73911:648829] -[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bbb347d8
2023-06-30 12:10:50.097927+0200 Runner[73911:648829] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bbb347d8'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180437330 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180051274 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180445e3c +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018043b224 ___forwarding___ + 1308
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018043d50c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   Runner                              0x0000000100687550 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader FIRFirestoreSettings] + 296
    6   Runner                              0x0000000100687240 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 1364
    7   Flutter                             0x0000000114bd5f18 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 52
    8   Runner                              0x0000000100689270 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader FIRFirestore] + 88
    9   Runner                              0x0000000100687208 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 1308
    10  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd5f18 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 52
    11  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd66fc FlutterStandardCodecHelperReadValueOfType + 784
    12  Runner                              0x00000001006872f0 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 1540
    13  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd5f18 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 52
    14  Runner                              0x0000000100688014 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader FIRQuery] + 64
    15  Runner                              0x0000000100687224 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 1336
    16  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd5f18 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 52
    17  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd66fc FlutterStandardCodecHelperReadValueOfType + 784
    18  Runner                              0x00000001006872f0 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 1540
    19  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd5f18 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 52
    20  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd4a98 -[FlutterStandardMethodCodec decodeMethodCall:] + 96
    21  Flutter                             0x0000000114bd22cc ___ZL39SetStreamHandlerMessageHandlerOnChannelPU31objcproto20FlutterStreamHandler8NSObjectP8NSStringPU33objcproto22FlutterBinaryMessengerS_PU29objcproto18FlutterMethodCodecS_PU27objcproto16FlutterTaskQueueS__block_invoke + 68
    22  Flutter                             0x00000001141c3a40 ___ZN7flutter25PlatformMessageHandlerIos21HandlePlatformMessageENSt21_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE10unique_ptrINS_15PlatformMessageENS1_14default_deleteIS3_EEEE_block_invoke + 108
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019a0528 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019a1d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019b2808 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1316
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019b22d4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018039a784 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180394de4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1912
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180394254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000188eb7c9c GSEventRunModal + 160
    31  UIKitCore                           0x000000010eb3eff0 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
    32  UIKitCore                           0x000000010eb42f3c UIApplicationMain + 124
    33  Runner                              0x0000000100680534 main + 64
    34  dyld                                0x00000001008e1514 start_sim + 20
    35  ???                                 0x0000000100b1de50 0x0 + 4306624080
    36  ???                                 0x9769000000000000 0x0 + 10910251572281737216
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It says that the error is in the file FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader but I don't understand how to fix it.
I've already done the iOS installation for firebase (added google-services for iOS and adding these lines in info.plist):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I've tried to reinstall pods a few times in different ways but it doesn't work.

Here is what flutter doctor -v says:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm64, locale
    fr-BE)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at
      /Users/tom.hnt/Desktop/developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (2 weeks ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tom.hnt/Library/Android/sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • E52DE536-EDA2-4A04-8C79-AC4EA3837DA7 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                •
      darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I'm trying to build my flutter app on iOS and to test in on a simulator